# My heading tag CSS works in my Wordpress page builder but not in my footer

Tags: html, css

For some reason, my headers are ignoring their CSS if I put them anywhere but my page builder plugin.

I'm using the following CSS at the very top of my stylesheet:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
color: #b8b8b8;
font-weight: 500;
}

h1 {font-size:65px;}

h2 {font-size:58px;}

h3 {font-size:42px;}

h4 {font-size:36px;}

h5 {font-size:28px;}

h6 {font-size:22px;}
```

You can see the problem in the link within my header below, there's a h1
at the top of the page that is working, and a h5 in the footer that is ignoring the css above.

```
<header class="header">
    <!-- LOGOS -->
    <a href="#">
        <img class="standard logo" src="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Lucie_Averill_Photography_Logo-2.png">
        <img class="white logo" src="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Lucie_Averill_Photography_Logo_White.png"></a>
    <!-- LOGOS -->
    <img class="menu button" src="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Menu.png">
    <!-- HEADER NAVIGATION MENU -->
    <nav class="header-nav">
        <div class="menu-header-menu-container">
            <ul id="menu-header-menu" class="menu">
                <li id="menu-item-463">
                    <a href="#">WORK</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-584"><a href="#">LANDSCAPES</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-473"><a href="#">SEASCAPES</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-478"><a href="#">MACRO</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-477"><a href="#">CITIES</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-475"><a href="#">LONG EXPOSURE</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-480"><a href="#">MISCELLANEOUS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-10"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-464"><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-923">
                    <a href="#">SOCIAL</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-11"><a target="_blank" href="#">FACEBOOK</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-924"><a href="#">INSTAGRAM</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-15"><a target="_blank" href="#">FLICKR</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                <li id="menu-item-14"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

My stylesheets are enqueued as the following:

```
    if  (is_page_template('page-templates/full-page.php'))  { 
 wp_enqueue_style( 'lucieaverillphotography-full-page' ,  
  get_template_directory_uri() . 
  '/css/full-page.css'); 
} 
else  { 
 wp_enqueue_style( 'lucieaverillphotography_style',  get_stylesheet_uri() ); 
} 
}    
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts',  'lucieaverillphotography_scripts' );
```

Comment: I know this is really basic, but I really appreciate that you indented your HTML. It's pretty rare these days...

Comment: Hah, yeah I ran it through a code formatter :)

Comment: Looking at your site, it looks like the header h1 and footer h5 are both sized using the CSS you posted above. Can you recreate a jsFiddle to show us the problem more directly? It can't be reproduced by what you have posted.

Answer (score 1):

because every other plugin or child theme override main stylesheet

your plugin has got `CSS` for headings which is overriding your theme `CSS`

and your custom `CSS` in plugin overrides everything, this is how plugins work, mainly those deal in designing and styling.

best way is "INSPECT ELEMENT" and check priorities of `CSS` and their url.

and  one more stuff, if i remember correctly bottom `CSS` override top `CSS`

Comment: Your answer is really hard to read/understand. Could you edit your answer so it's easier to understand? I tried to edit it, but I'm not even sure myself what you meant to say in some spots.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `<link...>` tag for the custom stylesheet after the link for the plugin's stylesheet, or add `!important` to your CSS statements in order to give them top priority.

Using `!important` looks like this:

```css
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #b8b8b8 !important;
    font-weight: 500 !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi 4castle, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by moving the <link...>. I've enqueued my stylesheets via PHP in the functions folder, which I've added to my question above.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with WordPress, but if you don't have access to the `<head>` tag for the webpage, then try using the `!important` method. The `<link>` tags are in the `<head>` of your webpage and are what add external CSS to your webpage. The last `<link>` has the highest precedence for "cascading" the styles.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry everyone, I've made a stupid error here – I must have accidentally wiped out the font-family css rule from the section of my stylesheet that styles the body of my site. I noticed this after DACrosby pointed out that the sizing seems to be working. Thanks for your answers, I'll check more carefully before posting next time!